# How to load images as background in LibGDx?

Tags: android, libgdx, live-wallpaper

I make live wallpaper and I have one issue. I want to set image as background and Eclipse show error:

```
01-10 10:37:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 99
01-10 10:37:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Texture width and height must be powers of two: 480x800
```

My code looks like:

```
public class Tapeta implements ApplicationListener {


    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture texture;
    private TextureRegion region;


    @Override
    public void create() {      
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/cat.jpg"));
        Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false); 

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        texture.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(texture, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

I'm looking for solution of my issue and I didn't find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the libGDX error message is actually helpful!

```
Texture width and height must be powers of two: 480x800
```

So the texture width and height must be one of: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048 (neither 480 nor 800 are on that list ...)

You've got this magic line:

```
Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);
```

but its after the texture is loaded.  If you put it *before* the texture load, does the exception go away?  (Including more of the exception backtrace in your question would be helpful). I believe this method is only available for the case where you know the underlying OpenGL ES 1.0 system supports the non-power-of-two texture extension.  Setting this flag won't fix hardware that really does not support power-of-two textures.  (I've no idea how much such hardware is left in the world though, so it may be harmless these days.)

The power-of-two texture requirement is a restriction of the hardware and OpenGL ES.  This requirement was dropped from OpenGL ES 2.0.

Another way to get around this requirement is to build a texture atlas that is power-of-two sized, and it contains your not-a-power-of-two textures within it.  Then you render subsections of the atlas image. See http://bitiotic.com/blog/2012/05/10/tutorial-for-texturepacker-and-libgdx/

Comment: For me I have to use `GLTexture.setEnforcePotImages(false);`